# WPF XAML Grid Visibility Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, visibility

I have a status message located on the first row of my grid and I want it to slide in and out when the visibility changes.
The first visibility trigger works great and slides the first grid row open quickly. As soon as I add the 'Collapsed' trigger, nothing works at all. How do I reverse the animation to slide closed when the visibility is set to collapsed?

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="55" Visibility="{Binding StatusMessageVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="55" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="55" To="0" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>                        
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <TextBlock Text="Hi There" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should remove the `Visibility` binding in your grid and use a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `StatusMessageVisibility` property. If you bind the grid's visibility then once it's collapsed it's collapsed and you won't be able to see the animation.

Also, instead of having two data triggers with `EnterActions`, use a single data trigger that also has an `ExitAction` for the collapsed state:

```xaml
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="55">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusMessageVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="55" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="55" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>               
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <TextBlock Text="Hi There" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: In my case the grid has to be collapsed by default, but if i remove binding from grid either it is always visible or always collapsed depending on how i initialize Visibility on the grid and datatriggers never kick in.  Seems like datatrigger do not update grid visibility. What can i do?

Comment: Seems like datatrigger do not update grid visibility