# WPF menu - Dynamic show and hide content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu

I need to create interactive menu. When option was choosen, I want to show appropriate content.
For example when option "Schemat bazy Northwind" was clicked, to my grid should be added Image. When another option was choosen previous content is removed and etc.

The only thing that comes to my mind is create functions which at the beginning clear grid and later add content(Is it possible?).

Please there anybody could direct me to solve this problem.

```
<Window x:Class="Northwind.AdminPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Panel administratora" WindowState="Maximized">

    <StackPanel Name="bindingData">
        <StatusBar>
            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding ServerName}" Margin="0 0 30 0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding ConnectionStatus}" Margin="0 0 30 0"></TextBlock>
            <Label FontSize="15" Name="lblClock"></Label>
        </StatusBar>

        <DockPanel Height="55">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="Baza" Margin="10" FontSize="15"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Pomoc" Margin="10" FontSize="15">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="itemSchema" Header="Schemat bazy Northwind" Click="itmSchema_Click_1"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
           </Menu>
        </DockPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="mainContent">  

          <!--add content -->                             

        </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace Northwind
{
    public partial class AdminPanel : Window
    {
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionStatus { get; set; }

        public AdminPanel(string name,string status)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.ServerName = name;
            this.ConnectionStatus = status;

            DispatcherTimer dtClockTime = new DispatcherTimer();
            dtClockTime.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dtClockTime.Tick += dtClockTime_Tick;

            dtClockTime.Start();
            bindingData.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void dtClockTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblClock.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        private void itmSchema_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //code
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the menu or whichever item you wanted to a conatainer (Grid) and you can use the Visibility attribute as collapsed when you want to hide that control.
if you are not using MVVM pattern then add it into the corresponding Event.

```
Container_Name.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Or else you can use the Xaml Triggers for obtain the same.
For that refer [StackOverflow_Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881851/wpf-xaml-grid-visibility-trigger)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your solution is very easy and it's works that I wanted. I created new containers for my XAML code and I Set them property Visbility with Collapsed value.
Maybe my question will be stupid but for Example in HTML we can set class and id on the elements. In XAML we can use only once Name property and in code behind I must write all containers Name to set Collapsed value. It's not problem but maybe it can be a little bit improved.

Comment: Iam suggesting you to do it all in MVVM Pattern. That is more easy.

Comment: I tried use MVVM Pattern. I read some about resource dictionary in wpf but unfortunately I had problem with an associated key attribute. 
I understand that use MVVM is more professional but now use property Visible is easier for me. Certainly in the future I will draw my attention to your solution. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a resources Dictionary and add this code

```
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!--  Set names two different ways  -->
    <Button Name="okButton">OK</Button>
    <Button x:Name="cancelButton">Cancel</Button>
    <ListBox>
        <!--  Set content three different ways  -->
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem.Content>Item 3</ListBoxItem.Content>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox> </StackPanel>
```

when option "Schemat bazy Northwind" was clicked

```
private void SchematbazyNorthwind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = null;
            using (FileStream fs =
            new FileStream("Dictionary1.xaml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                stackPanel = (StackPanel)XamlReader.Load(fs);
            }
            MainGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        }
```

Load your Resources and attach to you grid